# 'int' object has no attribute 'guild' discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Хочу сделать команду, которая будет выдавать и забирать роли. Но выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

Код:

```py
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
  user = ctx.author.id
  ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
  role = ds.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name='Ожидание')
  role2 = ds.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name='Вне игры')
  user.add_roles(role2)
  user.remove_roles(role)
  config.players = config.players - 1
```

Кто подскажет, где ошибка?

Comment: `user = ctx.author.id` => `user = ctx.author`

Comment: @Namerek `RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

Comment: `user = ctx.author.id` это число, просто `id` пользователя. И вы из этого объекта `user` пытаетесь получить объект сервера. Скорее всего, как уже написали выше, вам нужен просто `user = ctx.author`

Comment: @denisnumb  выдаёт ошибку которую я упоминул выше

Comment: Посмотрите на функции `add_roles` и `remove_roles` в списке методов [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member), также функцию `purge` у объекта канала [`discord.Channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel) - они должны быть асинхронными

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
  user = ctx.author
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
  role = ds.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name='Ожидание')
  role2 = ds.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name='Вне игры')
  await user.add_roles(role2)
  await user.remove_roles(role)
  config.players = config.players - 1
```

`ctx.author.id` - это число

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
  user = ctx.author
  ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
  role = ds.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name='Ожидание')
  role2 = ds.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name='Вне игры')
  user.add_roles(role2)
  user.remove_roles(role)
  config.players = config.players - 1
```

Comment: Нету асихронности